# How do I write an input loop in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

In C#, I would write this:

```
string input;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter an equation: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} while (FSharpOption<Expression>.get_IsNone(Infix.TryParse(input)));
```

This would prompt the user to enter an equation repeatedly until they enter one that can be parsed. How would I do this in F#?

Comment: It seems like you use MathNet.Symbolics

Comment: @FoggyFinder I am doing that in this particular case, but it's not relevant to my actual question

Comment: yeah, I know. You got the great answers but if there is something that not clear to you feel free to come to the F# chat room and get help. There is a central F# community - [F# slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) (I do really advise you to join) ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a recursive function:

```
let rec readInput () =
    Console.Write("Enter an equation: ")
    let input = Console.ReadLine()
    match Infix.TryParse(input) with
    | Some(e) -> e
    | None -> readInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit over the top but I once wrote the following:

```
let inputParseLoop msg parser =
    let isNull x = Core.obj.ReferenceEquals (x, null)
    Seq.initInfinite (fun _ ->
        printf "%s " msg
        try Some (stdin.ReadLine ()) with _ -> None)
    |> Seq.takeWhile Option.isSome
    |> Seq.map Option.get
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun s -> not (isNull s))
    |> Seq.map parser
    |> Seq.skipWhile Option.isNone
    |> Seq.head
    |> Option.get
```

For your use case, call it like this:

```
inputParseLoop "Enter an equation: " Infix.TryParse
```